# Get a MD5 value from a file using findstr in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have the following file contents from which I want to extract the MD5 hash value thats on line 2.

How can I do this in a Windows batch file? Unfortunately using powerscript is not an option.

Herewith the input file ( file.txt )

```
MD5hashoffile20160613190010_Address
f4f855c5cb40767a7227b506f641ceef
CertUtil:-hashfilecommandcompletedsuccessfully.
```

I wanted to use the **findstr** utility but the regex I use must be wrong since it's not returning anything.

```
findstr /R "[a-fA-F0-9]{32}" file.txt
```

I appreciate any advice.

Thanks

**UPDATE :**

I have added the full solution in the answer section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial and error I found a solution that works :

```
findstr /R "^[a-fA-F0-9]*$" file.txt
```

**Updated Answer with full solution :**

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "FILESIZE=0"
SET "RECORDCOUNT=0"
SET "MD5HASH="
SET "TEMPHASH="
SET "FILESETREPORT=_UNSET"
SET "LINE=0"
SET "COLUMNS=TableName|RecordCount|FileSize|FileHash"

echo "============================="
echo "= Starting FileSize process ="
echo "============================="

for %%F in (*.csv) do (
  echo "Process A CSV File"

  for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=^_" %%A IN ("%%~nF") do (  
    SET "TABLENAME=%%D"
    SET "FILESIZE=%%~zF" 
    if "!FILESETREPORT!" == "_UNSET" (       
      SET "FILESETREPORT=%%A_%%B_%%C_FilesetReport.csv"
      :: Initialize the headers
      echo !COLUMNS! > !FILESETREPORT!
    )        
  )  
  echo "Get RecordCount in CSV"
  if "!TABLENAME!" NEQ "FilesetReport" (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('more +1 %%F ^| find /v /c ""') do SET "RECORDCOUNT=%%I"
    echo "Generate File MD5 Hash"    
    certUtil -hashfile %%~nxF MD5 > hashfile    
    echo "Get the hash from the file"        
    for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%A in (hashfile) do (
      SET "TEMPHASH=%%A"
      :: call :cleanHash
      if !LINE! == 0 SET "LINE=1" && call :cleanHash      
    )

    :: Reset the Line Number
    SET "LINE=0"

    echo "Save File Details to FieldsetReport"
    echo "RecordCount : !RECORDCOUNT!"
    echo "FileSize : !FILESIZE!"
    echo "MD5Hash : !MD5HASH!"
    echo "TableName : !TABLENAME!"
    SET "OUTPUTLINE=!TABLENAME!|!RECORDCOUNT!|!FILESIZE!|!MD5HASH!"
    echo !OUTPUTLINE! >> !FILESETREPORT!

    :: Cleanup    
    del hashfile    
  )
)

echo "File Processing Completed"
exit /b 0

:cleanHash
echo "Remove all spaces from the MD5 hash"
:: for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /R "^[a-fA-F0-9]*$" !TEMPHASH!') do SET TEMPHASH=%%a            
SET "MD5HASH=!TEMPHASH: =!"
echo "********************************************************************"
echo !MD5HASH!

ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: `"^[a-fA-F0-9]*$"` regex would match even an empty line. `"^[a-fA-F0-9].*$"` regex would match `Certutil …` line. `findstr /I /R "^[a-f0-9].*[a-f0-9]$" file.txt` might work for _given_ file content although could give false match(es) for more complex file content…

Comment: @JosefZ you are correct. I changed my script accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using this:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1" %%a in (file.txt) do set "hash=%%a" &goto breakLoop
:breakLoop
echo %hash%
pause
```

This should work even if another line also contains only hexadecimal characters, and has the added benefit of putting the md5 hash in a variable, ready to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I already completed the for loop section. I was having issues with the regex. I will update the answer with the full piece of code.

Comment: I have added the full solution in the answer section. Thanks for your advice, much appreciated.